# Misuse of redo in a history class

Tags: java

I am a student in Computer Science. This semester, I have to make a project (a Sudoku). One of the features of this project is the setting up of a history. So I started to implement this feature.
The "undo" seems to work but I have a little problem with the redo. I think I understand where the bug is coming from, but I do not know how to fix it.

When I change the value of a "Case", I add the old "Case" to my history. This allows me to recover them with undo. However, when I "redo", the first action does nothing, and if If I do all the "redo" possible, it is missing an action. I think it comes from the fact that I only have the old values ​​and not the news. But if I add the news, the problem would be reversed (undo bug, redo works?).

If you have an idea or a track, I'm interested! thank you in advance !

Here is the code when i add an item to my history :

```
// IN MY HISTORY CLASS    
public E getCurrentElement() {
        return leftQ.getLast();
}

public void add(E e) {
    leftQ.addLast(e);
    rightQ.clear();
    currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
    endPosition = currentPosition;
}

// IN MY add actionPerformed
history.add(Case.duplicate(c)); // Add oldCase
c.addPossibleValue(++addedValues); // change old case
refresh();
```

Code when i "undo" (work) :

```
// IN MY HISTORY CLASS
public void goBackward() {
        currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        rightQ.add(leftQ.removeLast());
    }

// In my undo actionPerformed
c = history.getCurrentElement();
history.goBackward();
refresh();
```

Code when i "redo" (dont work) :

```
// IN MY HISTORY CLASS
public void goForward() {
        currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
        leftQ.addLast(rightQ.poll());
    }

// In my redo actionPerformed

history.goForward();
c = history.getCurrentElement();
refresh();
```

Here is the execution trace when I debug:
First i add 2 element to my history. So i have " 1 2 " on my Label.
at the end of the First undo :

```
LEFT : [Case : Candidates :[] 
] --> FIRST Element on history, empty
 RIGHT : [Case : Candidates :[1] // Second one, contains "1"
]
```

Second undo :

```
LEFT : []
 RIGHT : [Case : Candidates :[]
, Case : Candidates :[1]
]
```

then 2 redo :

```
LEFT : [Case : Candidates :[]
]
 RIGHT : [Case : Candidates :[1]
]

LEFT : [Case : Candidates :[]
, Case : Candidates :[1]
]
 RIGHT : []
```

My label only contains "1". I think that it comes from the fact that I always add the old value, and so that my history does not contain the state of the object before the first undo ... But I do not see how I could do.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, I should warn you that, if your instructor finds this, you could face accusations of plagiarism and/or allowing plagiarism.  You should instead create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem without giving away too much of your assignment solution.

Comment: As I wrote above, the code is only a small application created to illustrate my problem. All the code here is necessary for this application so you can understand my approach. Case and History are classes used in my project, and each method is used. So I do not see how to make a shorter example...

Comment: Surely you're not suggesting that you need all 283 lines of that code to do a redo?

Comment: I edited. I summarized as much as I could.

Comment: Can you also [edit] to tell us what your debugging efforts have shown you about the state of your queues at each point?

Comment: Edited with my execution trace.

Answer (score 0):

Using linked lists could be a great way to shorten down your undo / redo implementation. Store your turns as nodes in the list, so that whenever you take a turn, you generate a new node at the end of the list. inside of each node, save an int[3][3] of your board layout. When undo is called, step the board back by loading the board on the previous list node. when redo is called, that node is still there, and you can just step forward. By doing this, you can undo all the way back to turn 1, and then redo all the way up to turn x. Since this is just Sudoku, using a linked list will not require too much memory. This solution is not the best choice for more complex requirements.